# Using MorrisJS in ASP.Net MVC 4 with Entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to draw a morrisjs line chart. I have added the controller as shown below:`    public class OrdersPerYearsController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDataService db = new ApplicationDataService();

```
    // GET: OrdersPerYears
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var c = db.OrdersPerYear.ToList().ToArray();
        return Json(c, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}`
```

And below is the code for the view:

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Orders per year";
}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/ApplicationData/"

<p>Chart</p>

<div id="OrdersPerYear" style="height: 300px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.get('@Url.Action("Index")', function (result) {
            new Morris.Line({
                // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
                element: 'OrdersPerYear',
                // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
                // the chart.
                data: result,
                // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-values.
                xkey: 'Year',
                // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
                ykeys: ['TotalSales'],
                // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
                // chart.
                labels: ['Product']
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

When i test the app, it pulls data from the db and displays array as shown in the image below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsjSm.png)

I do not know what am doing wrong. I have followed the tutorial rom this site: https://gist.github.com/mattGuima/2d00ee3c87720e4b0353/

Thanks

Comment: are you sure result is returning correct data?

Comment: Yea, it is returning formatted json array

Comment: Here is the image: enter http://i.stack.imgur.com/vsjSm.png

Comment: Are you getting graph?

Comment: No... its is just displaying the raw json data

Comment: This is what am getting: [{"id":1,"Year":2000,"Product":"cofee","TotalSales":200.00},{"id":2,"Year":2000,"Product":"tea","TotalSales":150.00},{"id":4,"Year":2001,"Product":"cofee","TotalSales":150.00},{"id":5,"Year":2001,"Product":"tea","TotalSales":150.00},{"id":6,"Year":2002,"Product":"cofee","TotalSales":300.00},{"id":7,"Year":2002,"Product":"tea","TotalSales":400.00}]